# Calculating separate percentages after grouping the observations by two factors

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, group-by

I have grouped my dataset using "group_by" with two factors, and counted the number of observations falling into each category of interest for each resulting group, like this.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(a,a,b,a,b,c,a,c,a,b), y = c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0), var = c(inf, med, inf, sup, med, med, sup, inf, med, sup))

df1 %>% 
  group_by(x,y) %>% 
  count(var) -> conta_var

# A tibble: 9 × 4
# Groups:   x, y [5]
  x         y var       n
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <int>
1 a         0 inf       1
2 a         0 med       1
3 a         1 med       1
4 a         1 sup       2
5 b         0 inf       1
6 b         0 sup       1
7 b         1 med       1
8 c         0 inf       1
9 c         0 med       1
```

now i would like to add a new column called like n_perc which takes each n and divides it by the total number of observations for each combination of x-y

I could do it manually by first computing each n by filtering for each group:

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(x == "a", y = 1) %>% 
  nrow() -> n_f
```

and then adding the column using mutate with a nested ifelse function, but i'm confident there's a faster way to do it.

the end result would look like:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
# Groups:   x, y [5]
  x         y var       n   n_perc
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <int>    <dbl>
1 a         0 inf       1      0.5
2 a         0 med       1      0.5
3 a         1 med       1      0.33
4 a         1 sup       2      0.66
5 b         0 inf       1   ...
6 b         0 sup       1
7 b         1 med       1
8 c         0 inf       1
9 c         0 med       1
```

Comment: `conta_var |> mutate(n_perc = n / sum(n), .by = c(x, y))`. Or if you prefer `group_by` to `.by`, you can do `conta_var |> group_by(x, y) |> mutate(n_perc = n / sum(n))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a repex with a corrected version of your example dataframe. It rounds your values to 2dp but note the fourth value of n_perc rounds to .67 and not .66 as in your example output:

```
library(dplyr)

# Your corrected dataframe
df1 <- data.frame(x = c("a","a","b","a","b","c","a","c","a","b"),
                  y = c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0),
                  var = c("inf", "med", "inf", "sup", "med",
                          "med", "sup", "inf", "med", "sup"))

conta_var <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(x, y) %>% 
  count(var) %>%
  mutate(n_perc = signif(n / sum(n), 2)) %>%
  ungroup()

conta_var
# A tibble: 9 × 5
  x         y var       n n_perc
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <int>  <dbl>
1 a         0 inf       1   0.5 
2 a         0 med       1   0.5 
3 a         1 med       1   0.33
4 a         1 sup       2   0.67
5 b         0 inf       1   0.5 
6 b         0 sup       1   0.5 
7 b         1 med       1   1   
8 c         0 inf       1   0.5 
9 c         0 med       1   0.5
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked!  I didn't know ungroup() existed, and looking it up i found a question with basically the same question i had.


ps. in the example i had added a few of the values for n_perc manually to explain better what i wanted to do, that's why the rounding was off :p